# Add exsisting user to exist ldap group in php

Tags: php, html, ldap

Hello dear programers I have a problem,
 please help me Iget users[samacountname] from one group and want 
 to add into ldap existing group by samacountname? How can i di this in php?

Comment: This question is severely lacking detail, unfortunately. I think you're trying to do something with LDAP? There's some documentation here ( http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ldap.php ), but I think it'll be a bit of a mission to get this working with PHP. Why the preference for PHP?

Comment: Hi @Luke. Why is it "a mission to get that working with PHP" when we don't know what user3516998 wants to achieve?

Comment: @heiglandreas It appears that he wants to use PHP's LDAP services, and I believe you need to recompile PHP to get those working.

Comment: @luke Depends on how you installed PHP. On any default *nix- or Mac-Distros you can install the LDAP-Extension afterwards via your favourite package-manager. On Windows there is a DLL that has to be included so there is no need to recompile PHP. For more info on that have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php ;)